# I'm making a linked list of strings in C, and having a problems

Tags: c, string, data-structures, linked-list

I am beginner in programming. thanks for helping me.

I am trying to make a linked list in strings.
inputs are strings, and it ends if input is "exit".
But when i compile it, it prints out the last inputs only, and i can't solve it!
From function addrear, it distinguishes whether data is stored in linked list for the first time of not. and store data and links to another Node appropriately.
From function printlist, it starts from the start of linked list and prints out the data in each nodes.

I've tried it with integer type , and when this code was executed with int , not string, it worked correctly, so i think error came out from character array.

ex) input1 "dump",
input2 "end",
input3 "dir",
input4 "exit",

than output would be

dump,
end,
dir,
exit

but it comes out

exit
exit
exit
exit

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


char instruction[1000];

struct Node {
    struct Node* next;
    char* data;
};

struct Node* pStart = NULL;
struct Node* pEnd = NULL;

void addrear(char* val)
{
    struct Node* Current;
    Current = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    Current->data = val;
    Current->next = NULL;
    //printf("%s\n", Current->data);
    if (pStart == NULL)
    {
        pStart = Current;
        pEnd = Current;
    }
    else
    {
        pEnd->next = Current;

        pEnd = Current;
    }
}
void printlist(struct Node* Current)
{
    Current = pStart;
    while (Current != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", Current->data);
        Current = Current->next;
    }
}
int main()
{
    int i;

    while (1)
    {

        printf("sicsim> ");
        fgets(instruction, sizeof(instruction), stdin);
        instruction[strlen(instruction) - 1] = '\0';
        addrear(instruction);

        if (strcmp(instruction, "exit") == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    printlist(pStart);


}
```

Comment: 't prints out the last inputs only' got it...

Comment: There a a few, (!), duplicates under the 'linked-list' tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As MZB answered, your problem is you are confusing reference and value.

You said:
"I've tried it with **integer** type , and when this code was executed with int , not string, it worked correctly, so i think error came out from character array."

There's a huge difference between assigning the value of `int` and assigning a string. you are going to get the value of this `int` anyway- you don't care where he "lives". It is also true when we talk about `char`, but if you talk about strings - you want to *point* to this string - so you want to point at some place which can hold your data and would not be modified.

If you want to save this string you need to know that the string storage place would not be accessed.

Therefore you should copy char by char so you wouldn't care if "instruction" will be assign as something else.

Comment: Thanks to your advice, i changed the code by making new char arrays in addrear func and stored each characters one by one. and linked that new char array in linked list.
It worked out well in Visual Studio. But i am making a sic machine shell in putty, so I tried it in Putty. But It printed out only blank in Putty....

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is that you are storing a pointer to the instruction buffer in the Node structure. Each time you read a string, you overwrite that buffer with the string you read in.

You need to allocate memory for each string.

If you're learning C++, check out the documentation on "new" (how you should allocate the space for Node etc.) malloc is a lower-level C method of doing things.

Comment: Why are you mentioning C++ stuff? It's a question about C. Especially since you VERY rarely use `new` in modern C++.

Comment: Thanks to your advice, i revised the code and i succeeded in Visual Studio.
But when i did this in Putty, It is now only printing out blank spaces..